# A Javascript function named method

Tags: javascript, oop, methods

I found an implementation using using prototypes. This is a simplification to show the structure:

```
function Thingie(){
  this.content = [];
}

Thingie.prototype = {
  push: function(arg) {
    this.content.push(arg);
  },
  pop: function() {
    return this.content.pop();
  }
};

var t = new Thingie();
forEach([10, 3, 4, 8, 2, 9, 7, 1, 2, 6, 5],
        method(t, "push"));
```

What is "method" in the example on the last line? I've never seen this construct. I use t.push like everyone else.

I tried find how "method()" is defined online, but it is impossible to search for a function called "method" using any possible set of search terms. All you get are how functions and methods are defined and used. There also seems to be no information when I look at forEach documentation.

Does this make sense to anybody?

Comment: those `forEach` and `method` aren't standard functions. You have to look in the libraries you're using.

Comment: Open console and type in `method`, then hit Enter. You will see function definition.

Answer (score 0):

```
method(t, "push")
```

would be defined as:

```
function method(obj, name) {
   return obj[name].bind(obj);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That `forEach` looks like [UnderscoreJS's function _.each](http://underscorejs.org/#each)

```
_.each(list, iteratee, [context])          Alias: forEach

example: 
    _.each([1,2,3], function(item) { console.log(item); });

// console output:
// 1
// 2
// 3
```

That `method` probably looks like this (Beware: wild guess!) , giving you the function to use as `iteratee` paramater

```
function method(obj, name){
    if(typeof(obj[name]) != "function") 
        throw new Error("Not a function");
    return obj[name];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A function like that is [lodash.bindKey](https://lodash.com/docs#bindKey), which does exactly what you want. Also, the `forEach` method could be [lodash.forEach](https://lodash.com/docs#forEach), or simply [Array.prototype.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), which is built-in.

```
[1,2,3].forEach(_.bindKey(t, 'push'));
```

However, this works because `Thinghie#push` expects only one argument. If the same call would be made on an array, the result would not be as expected, since `forEach` methods take 3 arguments: `value, index, array`, and `[].push` can handle multiple arguments. So, the code

```
var array = [];
[1,2].forEach(_.bindKey(array, 'push'));
console.log(array); // outputs [1, 0, [1, 2], 2, 1, [1, 2]]
```

In this case (and in any case when we would like the function returned by `method` applied on only one argument), I guess the solution is to write

```
function method(obj, name) {
  return function(arg) { return obj[name](arg); }
}
```